# tkFileDialog askdirectory only jumping to initial directory at the first time

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter

My problem is, that when using `tkFileDialog.askdirectory`, the directory set for initialdir is always highlighted, as it should be, but the window is only scrolled down to it at the first time, any subsequent opened dialogs are stuck at the top.
Here is a minimal example to try:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, ttk


def get_dir():
    global dir
    dir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=dir, title="Select directory")


dir = "c:/work/test"  # Just enter any directory here that has to be reached by scrolling
root = Tkinter.Tk()
btn = ttk.Button(root, text="Open", command=get_dir)
btn.pack(side="left")
root.mainloop()
```

I am using python 2.7 and Windows 10, and I'm not sure if this problem is universal or platform specific, but if anyone has seen anything similar, I would appreciate the help.

The things I tried so far, but didn't work: setting a fixed initialdir instead of the last opened, replacing backslashes with forward slashes and vice versa

As requested, here are screenshots of what's happening:

This is how the dialog looks like when opened for the first time, initialdir selected, and scrolled down to:

[image: This is how the dialog looks like when opened for the first time]

And this is what happens after closing the dialog and opening it again, the initialdir is still selected, but it's scrolled to the top:

[image: This is how the dialog looks like when opened again]

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean... can you show me some screen-shots and explain.

Comment: I added screenshots, I hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Ahh... I understand your problem now but I can't help you there because I'm on Linux and askdirectory actually only shows the contents in the folder and not show a tree view like yours. you should add windows to your tags.

Comment: Old question, but why are you specifically specifying a root? What is wrong with the default?

Comment: The idea was to show the path that was loaded previously, to make navigation easier. For example, you have multiple test datasets in a common root folder, and want to switch between them.
The actual project is completely irrelevant now, I don't work at that company anymore, but I left the question here in case someone else runs into the same problem.